# VBA formatting number

Tags: excel, vba

I building a macro in excel that reads values from my workbook and fill a online form on a web-page, in one of cells I have a number, `126,25` (using comma to separate the decimal part) but when a submit this number to my online form the field display the value, `126.25`

How can I format the number to use the comma format? I already try read the value as text but the result is the same

```
'Read value from workbook
Number = Range("C6").Value
'Trying to format
Number = Format(Number, "###,##0")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
Sub dural()
    Number = Range("C6").Value
    Number = Replace(Number, ".", ",")
    MsgBox Number
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I am dealing with those issues constantly as I am in European format like you. 
I stopped wondering and simply do this systematically :

```
dim strNumber as string
'Read value from workbook
Number = Range("C6").Value
'Trying to format
strNumber = Format(Number, "###,##0")
strNumber = replace(strNumber,".",",")
```

1. Move the number properly formatted in a string
2. Replace any `.` with `,` in that string

That's maybe not the most *elegant* solution, but that's for me at least the *easiest* way to remind how to trick it.